# Definitions of projective tensor norm

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products

The Proposition 2.8 of Ryan's textbook(Introduction to tensor products of Banach spaces) says: Let $X$ and $Y$ be a Banach space. Let $u \in X\hat\otimes_{\pi} Y$ and $\epsilon >0$. Then there exist bounded sequences $(x_n), (y_n)$ in $X, Y$ respectively such that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n \otimes y_n$ converges to $u$ and 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \|x_n\|\|y_n\|<\pi(u)+\epsilon.
$$

From this we have that the projective norm $\pi (u)$ is that 
$$
\pi(u)=\inf\left\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \|x_n\|\|y_n\|:\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \|x_n\|\|y_n\|<\infty,\, u = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n \otimes y_n \right\},
$$
the infimum being taken over all the representations of $u$.

Question: Could you explain why 
$$
\pi(u) = \inf\left\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\lambda_n| \|x_n\|\|y_n\|:  u = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda_n x_n \otimes y_n, \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\lambda_n|<\infty,\, x_n, y_n \rightarrow 0\right\}?
$$

I have tried to show this by multiplying $x_n, y_n$ by some values to find the desired representation of $u$ (which is of the form as in the statement in Question), but I couldn't get it.

Comment: What is $X\hat\otimes_{\pi} Y$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair It is the completion of the normed space $X\otimes Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Try showing that if $u = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n \otimes y_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\lambda_n|<\infty$ for some sequence with $\lambda_n \ne 0$. Then if you let $\hat x_n = (1/\lambda_n)x_n$, it must be true that both $\hat x_n \to 0$ and $y_n = 0$.

Comment: If $\hat{x_n}=(1/\lambda_n) x_n$, how could you see that $\hat{x_n} \rightarrow 0$?